# Addition of 1 equivalent bromine to 1,3 pentadiene at temperature below 0 degree Celsius gives which compound?

Tags: c-c-addition

As far as I know reactivity of alkenes towards addition with halogens is directly proportional to their nucleophilicity, so bromine in this particular case should attack the double bond at Carbon-3 but in my textbook answer Bromine has been made to react with double bond at carbon-1
[image: this answer has been given]

Comment: I am confused. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: What is the solvent? At which pH and at which temperature is this?

Comment: Temperature below 0 degrees celsius and ph wasn't mentioned in the question